# @SpringBootTest OAuth2 JWT Token Authorization Fails Only In Integration Tests

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, spring-boot, integration-testing

- Spring Boot, Spring Security OAuth2 with JWT Access Token Authentication and Authorization work fine in full server run (tested in PostMan and Chrome) but not in Integration Tests
- @WithMockUser works for Controller unit tests
- @WithMockUser does not work for integration tests (I think because of the JWT implementation for access tokens)
- Set up RestTemplate exchange call to acquire access token for tests
- Fails with `java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode`
- Access Token fetching code:

  ```
  private String getAccessToken() throws Exception {
      String urlString = "/oauth/token";
      HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = getAccessTokenRequest();

      ResponseEntity<JSONObject> responseEntity = restTemplate
              .exchange(urlString, HttpMethod.POST, request, JSONObject.class);
      assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());

      JSONObject userJson = responseEntity.getBody();
      assertNotNull(userJson.get("access_token"));
      assertEquals("bearer", userJson.get("token_type"));

      return userJson.getString("access_token");
  }

  private HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> getAccessTokenRequest() {
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers = setBasicAuthHeaders(headers);
      headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
      headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

      MultiValueMap<String, String> requestMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
      requestMap.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
      return new HttpEntity<>(requestMap, headers);
  }

  private HttpHeaders setBasicAuthHeaders(HttpHeaders headers) {
      String authorization = "Basic " + new String(Base64Utils.encode("test:testsecret".getBytes()));
      headers.add("Authorization", authorization);
      return headers;
  }
  ```
- Integration Test (Always errors in the `getAccessToken()` function call):

  ```
  @Test
  public void createCustomer() throws Exception {
      String accessToken = getAccessToken();

      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.add("Bearer", accessToken);
      HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

      ResponseEntity<Customer> responseEntity = restTemplate
              .exchange("/api/2.0/customers/save"+
                      "?firstName=" + customerToSave.getFirstName() +
                      "&lastName=" + customerToSave.getLastName(),
                      HttpMethod.GET, entity, Customer.class);

      Customer customer = responseEntity.getBody();
      assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
      assertEquals(customerToSave.getLastName(), customer.getLastName());
  }
  ```
- Test class annotations:

  ```
  @ActiveProfiles("test")
  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
  @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
  ```

Comment: Got the same problem, If i run multiple because of @ActiveProfiles it doesn't work.